# Rails ActiveRecord Postgresql - Unable to find result executing a where on a JSON type Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have my json stored on a json column(parsed_document) on Postgresql:

```
{ "purchase_order": "8422" }
```

On my rails controller I'm trying to fetch the column parsed_document :

```
Orders.where("parsed_document ->> 'purchase_order' = '8422'")
```

**It's returning no results**. What Am I missing?

Thank you.

Rails output:

```
[19] pry(main)> SapWrite.where("parsed_document ->> 'purchase_order' = '8422'")
=>   SapWrite Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "sap_writes".* FROM "sap_writes" WHERE 
(parsed_document ->> 'purchase_order' = '8422')
[]
```

I found the problem. It was me unfortunately. I was extracting the JSON from an MSQL server and parsing it two times.

```
records.each do |row| 
  parsed_document = row["parsed_document"] 
  json_parsed_document = JSON.parse(parsed_document) 
  @SapWrite = SapWrite.new(parsed_document:json_parsed_document.to_json) 
  @SapWrite.save 
end
```

At the database the JSON was apparently right but it wasn't.

**So I removed the to_json from json_parsed_document variable and now it's writing the json properly and now I can query the json field.**

JSON inserting before:

```
{\\\"purchase_order\\\":\\\"8314\\\"}
```

**JSON after:**

```
{\"purchase_order\":\"8314\"}
```

Comment: It would be better to show this query in the console to isolate it from whatever is happening during the request cycle. `rails console`

Comment: Changed.It's returning an empty array.

Comment: This looks like it should work. Are you sure that `purchase_order` is a string? Can you try querying it without the quotation marks? Also, for completeness sake, it's not returning an array but an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is output as `[]` on the console.

Comment: @ma_il  you are right it's a AcitveRecord_Relation my fault. Same result without the quotation marks. Thanks.

Comment: @muistooshort it's return the json.